# How to config Apache2 to redirect URL

Tags: redirect, apache2

I am trying to config url redirect in Apache. I have tried some approaches and nothing works. Can someone tell me the solution of this as it doesn't seem too difficult.

I am going to redirect request from:

```
https://myhost/configuration/jmx-console
```

to:

```
http://myanohterhost/jmx-console
```

This is a https to http re-direct.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You could use the `RedirectMatch`  directive to force Apache to send the user someplace else:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherserver.com$1
```

See the following:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, this is not exactly what I need. Redirect does a browser redirect and the newly directed URL will be displayed in the browser. What I need is a way that only the contents of the new URL myanohterhost/jmx-console is displayed. The URL in the browser still displays https:// myhost/configuration/jmx-console

Comment: Not so. You merely copied your comment to the other poster. I tried this on my server just now and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

The normal way to do this would be the following, in the configuration of the current server (or virtual host) `myhost':

```
Redirect /configuration/jmx-console http://myanohterhost/jmx-console
```

Edit:
According to your comment, it looks like you can do it using one of the following techniques:

#### 1. mod_proxy, using a reverse proxy setup

Simply map the remote server's urls to a local url:

```
ProxyPass /configuration/jmx-console http://myanohterhost/jmx-console
ProxyPassReverse /configuration/jmx-console http://myanohterhost/jmx-console
```

#### 2. mod_rewrite using the proxy throughput feature

```
RewriteRule ^configuration/jmx-console(.*)$ http://myanohterhost/jmx-console$1 [P]
```

There can be some caveats in using reverse proxying like this, I recommend you to read thoroughly http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_proxy.html to see the various options available when using reverse proxying.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, this is not exactly what I need. Redirect does a browser redirect and the newly directed URL will be displayed in the browser. What I need is a way that only the contents of the new URL http://myanohterhost/jmx-console is  displayed. The URL in the browser still displays https:// myhost/configuration/jmx-console.

Answer (score 3):

Refering to the question title *How to config Apache2 to redirect URL* I would propose simple solution which works fine for me (using `RedirectPermanent` from `mod_alias`).

Firstly we check if our domain has proper DNS entries, as example `A` type entry:

```
name somefancydomain.com
TTL 600
type A
value 10.100.10.100
```

and `CNAME` entry:

```
name www.somefancydomain.com
TTL 600
type CNAME
value somefancydomain.com
```

Then we go to ubuntu webserver with IP 10.100.10.100 and configure new virtual host:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo vim redirect.conf
```

Paste configuration as below and save:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName somefancydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.somefancydomain.com

    RedirectPermanent / https://redirectedurl.com/

    ServerAdmin admin@redirectedurl.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Enable new virtual host and reload apache:

```
sudo a2ensite redirect.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Finally check if redirection is working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apache site you should **not** use mod_rewrite for simply redirecting from http to https (or the other way, which seems more common):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html

The website suggests using **mod_alias** with the **Redirect** and **RedirectMatch** directives.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this on your hosts "myhost"

1/ touch /etc/apache2/conf-available/my-redirect.conf

2/ edit my-redirect.conf and add

```
Redirect permanent /configuration/jmx-console http://myanotherhost/jmx-console
```

3/ a2enconf my-redirect.conf

4/ apache2ctl configtest

5/ this should give "Syntax OK"

6/ systemctl restart apache2