# How to redirect a site subfolder to a page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, server

I have a multi language site
I want :

`exemple.be/nl/`

to redirect to

```
exemple.be/nl/start_nl.php
```

and

`exemple.be/fr/`

to redirect to

`exemple.be/fr/start_fr.php`

Can I do this, possibly with .htaccess?

I tried this, to no avail:

```
301 /nl/ https://exemple.be/nl/start_nl.php
```

Comment: I think one language site view in your url? if is it you can pass by anchor tag or using javascrip or php using url redirect function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config Apache2 to redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596066/how-to-config-apache2-to-redirect-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on another site
In the .htaccess file, I wrote :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nl/?$ https://exemple.be/nl/nl-start.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fr/?$ https://exemple.be/fr/fr-start.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called setlocale in php that be of use for making it so that it goes to a specific site with header("Location: start_nl.php");

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

But otherwise you can make so so the index.php goes to the specific site with header("Location: start_fr.php");
Just put in on the top, under the opening tag for php:

```
<?php
header("Location: start_fr.php");
?>
```

It can also be done with html.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=start_fr.php">
```